# Manifest for specific flavor+type combination

Tags: android, gradle, manifest, android-productflavors

In my app I have two flavor dimensions: `device`, `environment`

And such flavors:

```
standard {
  dimension = "device"
  ...
}
custom {
 dimension = "device"
 ...
}
dev {
  dimension = "environment"
  ...
}
prod {
 dimension = "environment"
 ...
}
```

Now I want to have something specific in manifest for customRelease combination (regardless "environment" flavor dimension).

I have created a file `src/customRelease/AndroidManifest.xml` but Android Studio does see this file.
If I put manifest to `src/customDevRelease/AndroidManifest.xml` then this works for me but I also need to put the manifest here `src/customProdRelease/AndroidManifest.xml` which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting manifest path for some build variants:

```
def manifestSkygolfReleaseFile = 'src/customRelease/AndroidManifest.xml'        

sourceSets {
    customDevRelease {
        manifest.srcFile manifestSkygolfReleaseFile
    }

    customProdRelease {
        manifest.srcFile manifestSkygolfReleaseFile
    }
}
```

This isn't an ideal solution because in future if I add another type of environment (test) I'll need to not forget to add a piece of code to gradle:

```
    customTestRelease {
        manifest.srcFile manifestSkygolfReleaseFile
    }
```

Even worse my actual app has 4 flavor dimensions.